# R - extract output into a dataframe

Tags: r, output

I have run a statistical analysis (Support Vector Machine package e1071) in R and I want to extract part of the output into a vector.
For example:

```
>library(e1071)
>a<-c(0,0,1,1,1)
>b<-c(2,4,5,5,5)
>c<-c(5,6,7,3,7)
>a<-as.factor(a)
>model<-svm(a~b+c,probabiity=TRUE,method="C-classification") #build a SVM classification model

>b<-c(4,4,5,6,7)
>c<-c(4,6,7,3,7)
>test<-data.frame(b,c) ## test data
>probability<-predict(model,test,probability=TRUE)
>probability 

1 2 3 4 5 
0 0 0 0 0 
attr(,"probabilities")
    0   1
1 0.5 0.5
2 0.5 0.5
3 0.5 0.5
4 0.5 0.5
5 0.5 0.5
Levels: 0 1
```

and I want to extract all the data in column "1" and store it in a vector
How can I do this?

Comment: What is the current format of your output? A String?

Comment: how can I check this?

Comment: You need to give us the results of `str()` on that object, although it's possible you didn't save it to an object. Show us the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you show the full console output you can see that the data you want is stored in an 'attribute' with a name of "probabilities" for which you need to use the `attr` function to extract it:

```
> str(probability)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "0","1": 1 1 1 1 1
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
 - attr(*, "probabilities")= num [1:5, 1:2] 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : chr [1:5] "1" "2" "3" "4" ...
  .. ..$ : chr [1:2] "0" "1"
> attr(probability, "probabilities")
    0   1
1 0.5 0.5
2 0.5 0.5
3 0.5 0.5
4 0.5 0.5
5 0.5 0.5
```

And since you only want to store the first column, you use the `[` function with the j-argument set to the number (or the character name  which is the same in this case) of the column

```
myvals <- attr(probability, "probabilities")[ , '1']
myvals
  1   2   3   4   5 
0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5 0.5
```

Comment: I have the same issue, but when I try your solution, I get subscript out of bounds

Comment: My solution was tailored to the problem. We have no way to know what your problem (7 years later) might be.

Answer (score 0):

Using the data you provided

```
df <- structure(list(X0 = c(0.9457661, 0.9394421, 0.9348035, 0.9393719, 
0.9409816, 0.9390066, 0.9391518, 0.9407844), X1 = c(0.05423386, 
0.0605579, 0.06519648, 0.06062806, 0.05901843, 0.06099342, 0.06084821, 
0.05921564)), .Names = c("X0", "X1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("3", 
"6", "9", "12", "14", "16", "19", "25"))

vector <- df[,1]

vector
[1] 0.9457661 0.9394421 0.9348035 0.9393719 0.9409816 0.9390066 0.9391518
[8] 0.9407844
```

Comment: thanks, but the output is actually really long, with over 2000 rows.  Can I somehow extract data automatically?

Comment: A quick way would be to append the `[,1]` to the end of `predict(model, test, probability=TRUE)`. Without a more complete reproducible example, to go along with your question, it's hard to say more. You can have a look at [this how-to-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).